# How to set the "correct" tracking with fontspec and microtype (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, typography, microtype, garamond

I'm using LuaTeX with Garamond Premier font. For some reason, enabling `tracking` from `microtype` package changes the tracking of small caps quite considerably. Maybe too much? See the pictures:

With `tracking=false` (or without the whole `microtype` package):
[image]

With `tracking=true`:

[image]

When using `tracking=true`, I seem to get no change to output if I also specify `%\SetTracking{encoding=*, shape=sc}{100}`. So the default tracking value seems to be 100 for small caps when tracking is enabled.

**Q**: Which one or what is the correct tracking I should be using? I know how to change the tracking, but I don't know what would be the desired target.

Is there an objective truth here? I'd rather not set anything manually. Or is this 100% subjective thing and I need to decide it by myself by tweaking the tracking value? To my eye the 100 looks a bit too sparse so I'd bring it down a few notches.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\setmainfont[]{Garamond-Premier-Pro.ttf}

\begin{document}
Normal text. \textsc{small caps}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: as this is primarily an aesthetic question, there's no objective answer. If 100 seems too much to you (and I tend to agree), you can change the default with, say, `letterspace=75` (or the `SetTracking` command).

Comment: Thanks, @Robert. I was not initially sure if I was seeing a problem in font rendering or just the result of some subjective choices of `microtype` package. It indeed seems that the package defaulted to a sparse letter spacing/tracking with SC fonts. And now I know how to change that.

Answer (score 8):

According to Robert Bringhurst's “The Elements of Typographic Style”, version 3.0, page 30:

> The normal value for letterspacing these sequences of small or full caps is 5% to 10% of the type size. If your software sees the em as 1000 PostScript units, that means 50 to 100 units of letterspacing.

Usually I prefer `fontspec`'s integrated tracking support for that. The unit is percent of the type size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}[
  SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=7.5,Ligatures={}}
]
\begin{document}

Normal text. \textsc{small caps}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In fact with `fontspec` you can emulate almost all features of `microtype`. To also enable expansion and protrusion, use a preamble like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\adjustspacing=2
\protrudechars=2
\newfontfeature{MicroType}{expansion=default,protrusion=default}
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}[
  MicroType,
  SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=100,Ligatures={}}
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually already tried that. And thanks for the tip: I'll definitely try without `microtype` if relevant stuff can be achieved without it.

But my question was not how to change the tracking, but rather: how to achieve the "correct" tracking? Does your answer imply that the tracking without `microtype` package would be the correct one?

Comment: Additional question: `fontspec`documentation does not even mention "expansion" or "protrusion". So I guess these are LuaTeX features? Is there any documentation on how tp properly enable and config those features somewhere?

Comment: @Paapaa Protrusion and expansion are always handled by the underlying TeX engine. I don't know why `fontspec` doesn't provide high-level interfaces for that. In pdfTeX expansion and protrusion are a bit cumbersome to configure which is why `microtype` exists, but in LuaTeX these can be configured with Lua code. Here is an example for configuring the protrusion vectors: https://gist.github.com/hmenke/b8a1e7c47b92b8cf8778efa7d3eef315

Comment: @Paapaa If you want even more in-depth information you can look at [Fonts out of ConTeXt](https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf). This manual is specific to ConTeXt but since the LuaTeX font loader `luaotfload` is essentially a stripped-down version of the ConTeXt font loader a lot of stuff applies to it too.

Comment: @Paapaa I've also added a recommendation for letterspacing from one of my favorite typography books to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Henri Menke! Will take a look at the links. I also found where that default `100` for `microtype` is probably coming. There is a `\def\MT@letterspace@default{100}` in the `microtype` source code. I didn't yet find out why it seems to affect only small caps. But anyway. And 100 translates to the 10% upper bound Bringhurts mentions. I'll probably go with at most 5%. Ie. `LetterSpace=5.0` for a bit tighter look. And I'm happy to get rid of `microtype`.